# DB2 trigger which update

Tags: sql, triggers, db2

I am trying to update another table with a trigger. Here is my code:

```
   CREATE TRIGGER REORDER
         AFTER UPDATE OF ON_HAND
         REFERENCING NEW AS N
         FOR EACH ROW
         WHEN (N.ON_HAND < 0.1)
         BEGIN ATOMIC
         UPDATE SRI set SRI.price = SRI.price*10 where SRI.CODE = N.CODE;
    END
```

I get the following error:

> An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "CODE =
>   N.CODE". Expected tokens may include: ""..
>   SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.68.61

Comment: An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "CODE = N.CODE".  Expected tokens may include:  "<delim_semicolon>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.68.61

Comment: Can you have `//` comments there? Also, perhaps you need `;` after the UPDATE.

Comment: the comment is not in the code and I have add ;  the error is related to this delimiter

Comment: Review of my 05-Aug *answer* will show how a different parser [than used by the OP] diagnoses that 05-Aug updated trigger source, giving what is probably a much clearer *picture* of where the problem originates; i.e. the error will be found nearer to the REFERENCING clause rather than near the END-OF-STATEMENT. I figure my shorter answer was just as clear, but apparently down-voting is a sport amongst some whom, for which testing what's offered is anathema; my longer answer shows iteratively the effects actually seen, as *proof* of actually having performed the tests myself, per feedback seen.

Answer (score 0):

The following scripted requests, show a setup followed by two failing requests and a successful request; the first CREATE TRIGGER is essentially identical [except formatting and naming of the trigger] to that from the OP, and the remaining two are the result of their minor revisions:

Setup:

```
create table on_hand_table (code char, on_hand dec(3, 1) )
; -- Table ON_HAND_TABLE created
create table sri (code char, price dec(7, 2) )
; -- Table SRI created
```

Several CREATE TRIGGER requests; the full trigger name is used to explain the effective mods instituted from the prior iteration, and the comment following each request describes the outcome as experienced running IBM DB2 for i 7.1:

```
 create trigger ReOrder_source_unchanged               
 after update of ON_HAND                               
 referencing NEW as N                                  
 for each row                                          
 when (N.ON_HAND < 0.1 )                               
 begin ATOMIC                                          
    UPDATE SRI                                         
      set SRI.price = SRI.price*10                     
    WHERE SRI.code  = N.code                           
    ;                                                  
 end                                                   
 -- Keyword REFERENCING not expected. Valid tokens: ON OR.
```

```
 create trigger ReOrder_OF_Changed_to_ON
 after update on ON_HAND              
 referencing NEW as N                 
 for each row                         
 when (N.ON_HAND < 0.1 )              
 begin ATOMIC                         
    UPDATE SRI                        
      set SRI.price = SRI.price*10    
    WHERE SRI.code  = N.code          
    ;                                 
 end                                  
 -- Table ON_HAND not found.
```

```
 create trigger ReOrder_both_OF_and_ON
 after update of ON_HAND              
              on ON_HAND_TABLE        
 referencing NEW as N                 
 for each row                         
 when (N.ON_HAND < 0.1 )              
 begin ATOMIC                         
    UPDATE SRI                        
      set SRI.price = SRI.price*10    
    WHERE SRI.code  = N.code          
    ;                                 
 end                                  
 -- Trigger REORDER_BOTH_OF_AND_ON created
```

Answer (score -1):

The `ON table-reference` seems to be missing from the CREATE TRIGGER given in the OP; only the `OF column-name` is coded.  Might that be the source of the problem, albeit an odd location being diagnosed for that problem with the syntax.?

```
 create trigger ReOrder 
 after update of ON_HAND /* this names the column being updated */
              on ON_HAND_TABLE /* this is missing from OP */
 referencing NEW as N   
 …
```

Comment: Good catch  but I think it still needs a if not a when.

Comment: I can not tell anyone what to think, but what I showed [as the only change], created a trigger just fine for me.  The syntax from the manual even shows `WHEN--(--search-condition--)-` which is exactly what the OP had coded; and presumably is why I was able to create a DB2 TRIGGER using the original source, with just that minor change I suggested.